# Missing ID laravel 8 update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i make a update function in laravel 8. when i need to update court data, parameter id is missing. in my code i think i give my id what should i do ?

## table-data-court.php

this my view code

```
<!-- Hoverable Table rows -->
<div class="card">
    <h5 class="card-header">Data Court</h5>
    <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
        <table id="example" class="table datatables-basic table-hover p-3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nama Wahana</th>
                    <th>Nama Court</th>
                    <th>Foto</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
                @foreach ($data as $court)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $court->nama_tempat }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $court->nama }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Button Details -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#modalCenter-{{ $court->court_id }}" data-id="{{ $court->court_id }}">
                                <i class='bx bxs-user-detail'></i>
                            </button>
                            <!-- Modal Details -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="modalCenter-{{ $court->court_id }}" tabindex="-1"
                                aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalCenterTitle">Foto Lapangan</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="row g-2">
                                                <div class="col-md">
                                                    <img src="{{ $court->foto }}" class="circle-rounded" alt="foto"
                                                        width="200px" height="200px">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- / Modal Details -->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Button Details -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#ModalScrollable-{{ $court->court_id }}"
                                data-id="{{ $court->court_id }}">
                                <i class='bx bxs-edit-alt'></i>
                            </button>
                            <!-- Modal Details -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalScrollable-{{ $court->court_id }}" tabindex="-1"
                                aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                                    <form class="modal-content" method="POST"
                                        action="{{ route('court.update', $court->court_id) }}"
                                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('PUT')
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalCenterTitle">Edit Court</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $court->court_id }}">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col mb-3">
                                                    <label for="nama" class="form-label">Nama Court</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama"
                                                        name="nama" value="{{ $court->nama }}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col mb-3">
                                                    <label for="foto" class="form-label">Foto Court</label>
                                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="foto"
                                                        name="foto">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                                                data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                                                Tidak
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- / Modal Details -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/ Hoverable Table rows -->
```

## Web.php

and my routes code

```
Route::get('/manage-court', [App\Http\Controllers\ManageCourtController::class, 'index']);
Route::put('/manage-court/{id}/', [App\Http\Controllers\ManageCourtController::class, 'update'])->name('court.update');
```

## Controller

controller manage-court

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = Court::join('wahana_olahraga', 'wahana_olahraga.wahana_id', '=', 'court.wahana_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.user_id', '=', 'wahana_olahraga.user_id')->select('nama_tempat', 'nama', 'court.court_id as idCourt')->where('users.user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->get();
        return view('Pemilik.pages.manage-data-court', compact('data'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = Court::find($id);
        if (!$data) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'User not found'], 404);
        }
        $data->nama = $request->input('nama');
        $data->save();
        return redirect()->route('manageCourt')->with('success', 'Data berhasil diubah');
    }
```

## Error

and when i run the code show this error, what should i do ?

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: court.update] [URI: manage-court/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-wahana-olahraga-main\resources\views\Pemilik\components\table-data-court.blade.php)
```

i need make a update data in my project laravel 8 and the update function error like that, what should i change in my code ? sorry if my english so bad. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the param key in `route`.

`route('court.update', ['id => $court->court_id])`